# What is a multidimensional function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I've just started with multivariable caculus and I wondered what exactly a multidimensional function is.

In general a function might be defined as $f: \mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}^m $. This function has a multidimensional domain and a multidimensional codomain.

So if someone is just talking about a multidimensional function is they referring to the domain or to the codomain?

So is $f: \mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R} $ or $f: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}^m $ considered as an one dimensional function? If they both are multidimensional, does it mean there are multiple combinations of say how a four dimension function is defined (Could you tell me which)?

Example, where I didn't understand what functions are actually meant: I learned that from differentiability follows continuity for one dimensional functions, but it isn't the case for multidimensional functions.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: A function does not have a dimension, but its domain and codomain might.

Comment: A better term is "multi-variable."  A univariable function is $f(x)$ while a multi-variable function is $f(x,y)$ or $f(x,y,z,\ldots)$.

Comment: hmm that's a little bit confusing. I just googeld for "multidimensional function", but in my target language "mehrdimensionale Funktionen" seems to be more a thing. 

I also know the term "multi-variable" and I've heard of scalar-function and vector-function (or something similar).

Comment: Honestly, I've seen the term "multidimensional/miltivariable" refer to both the domain and target space. I've also seen things like "multivariable vector-valued function", or "multivariable scalar function" or stuff like that to mean functions $f:\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}^m$ or $f:\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}$ respectively. Also I've heard terminology like "$Y$-valued function on $X$" to mean a function $f:X\to Y$. My point is that terminology is not rigid. Often times you have to deduce meaning from context, because the same terms can be used with (slightly) different meanings in different contexts.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Yeah I know that terminalogy is not always clear and not used correctly by everyone. Although mostly there is some general agreement on when a term is certainly used wrongly :-) 
I guess I then just have to ask my professor to say more precisely what he means by sentences like the example in the question. Although I believe there might be a general agreement that everything that is not $\mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ is multidimensional.